# how to change date into DD/MM/YYY format and then into text using postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

```
select
    dt.client_id,
    dt.user_id,,
    CAST(DATE(dt.created_on) AS TEXT) as created_on,
    dt.created_by,
    dt.last_update_on,
    dt.last_update_by
from
    draft dt
where
    dt.user_id = 'ABC'
    and CAST(DATE(dt.created_on) AS TEXT) LIKE LOWER('%2020-10-30%')
```

here created_on is datetime column which need to formatted first into YYYY-MM-DD format then need to convert into text

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your question is also quite unclear.

Comment: You cannot change a date into DD/MM/YYYY, and then into text because, as soon as you are applying a format it becomes text. (and no longer is a date, it might represent a date, but it is text!)

Answer (score 1):

To format the value, us [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html):

```
to_char(dt.created_on, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as created_on
```

But you shouldn't use LIKE for DATE (or TIMESTAMP) values.

Assuming `created_on` is a `timestamp` (there is no `datetime` data type in Postgres) you can cast it to a `date` to compare it with a `date` value:

```
where cast(dt.created_on as date) = date '2020-10-30'
```

For performance reasons using a range condition on the `timestamp` column might be better if it's indexed:

```
where dt.created_on >= date '2020-10-30' 
  and dt.created_on < date '2020-10-30' + 1
```